# Laravel, composer require laravel/ui, remove laravel/framework v7.25.0

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have been trying to set up this code and composer give me following error
when I run the command: `composer require laravel/ui`

I have been trying to search for solutions for this error, however, nothing really seems to work.

I get the following error:

```
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.25.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.25.0
    - laravel/ui 3.x-dev requires illuminate/support ^8.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[8.x-dev], illuminate/support[8.x-dev, v8.0.0, v8.0.1, v8.0.2, v8.0.3, v8.0.4, v8.1.0, v8.2.0, v8.3.0, v8.4.0, v8.5.0, v8.6.0].
    - laravel/ui v3.0.0 requires illuminate/support ^8.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[8.x-dev], illuminate/support[8.x-dev, v8.0.0, v8.0.1, v8.0.2, v8.0.3, v8.0.4, v8.1.0, v8.2.0, v8.3.0, v8.4.0, v8.5.0, v8.6.0].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[8.x-dev, v7.25.0].
    - don't install illuminate/support 8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.25.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.25.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.25.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.25.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.25.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.25.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.25.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.25.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.25.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.25.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.25.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.25.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v7.25.0, required as ^7.25) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.25.0].
    - Installation request for laravel/ui ^3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[3.x-dev, v3.0.0].
```

Here is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.25",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my composer.lock file: https://pastebin.pl/view/ce7d64b9

Comment: Can you post your composer.json/composer.lock files?

Comment: It looks like you've got laravel 7.25 and the newest version of `laravel/ui` is expecting you to have laravel 8. It seems you'll need to update your app to laravel 8 or specify an earlier version of `laravel/ui` that was compatible with laravel 7

Comment: Try running `composer require laravel/ui:^2.4` [per this doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend)

Comment: @CurtisKelsey I have updated my post.

Comment: @WesleySmith that seems to work better, however, I run into a new error. proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory

Comment: That sounds like you're running out of system memory, see this question for more on that error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611099/composer-proc-open-fork-failed-cannot-allocate-memory

Comment: After some solutions were proposed: where are you currently stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
composer require laravel/ui:^2.4
```